# sed: command garbled for solaris

Tags: sed, solaris

I am trying to append the lines

```
<configuration>
      <jsp-configuration
       display-source-fragment="false"
       x-powered-by="false"/>
    </configuration>
```

after line

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" enabled="false"/>
```

i am trying this command

```
sed -i '/<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" enabled="false"\/>/a <configuration>\n <jsp-configuration\n display-source-fragment=\"false\"\n x-powered-by=\"false\"/>\n </configuration>' abc.xml >output.xml
```

this is working fine for Unix but not working for solaris,giving  command garbled error

Answer (score 1):

The error may come from the space after your `a` command. Try remove it. Or, better: put your script in a file and write it like that:

```
/<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" enabled="false"\/>/a\
 <configuration>\
 <jsp-configuration\
 display-source-fragment="false"\
 x-powered-by="false"/>\
 </configuration>
```

It's important that the very last character of the lines in your script be the backslash, except for the last of the appended lines. You name this file e.g. `sedscr`, and then:

```
sed -f sedscr abc.xml >output.xml
```

By the way, why did you use the option `-i` while redirecting the output to another file?

Comment: if a space is needed on `a` action it is before the a not after (and before the `\`). Use a differnet pattern separator `\|TheRegexPattern|` for better reading when `/` are in the pattern and a bit long like here. option `-i` is available on solaris (not on mine) ?